# Cannot run a compiled program

Tags: c++, curl

I used the source from here

http://www.luckyspin.org/?p=28

I downloaded cURL and built it with Visual Studio SDK CMD. I then pasted that code in Visual Studio 2010 (GUI) and added the needed paths and libs.

The program compiled fine, but on run it prompted for MSVCR90.dll. I found that file and copied it over to system32 folder.
When i then ran the program i got the error

```
R6034 An application has made an attempt to load C runtime library incorrectly. Please contact the applications suport team for more information.
```

I tried then compiling it with Dev-Cpp as well, same thing.

What is wrong?

Comment: You cannot copy msvcr90.dll like that, it needs to be deployed into the Windows side-by-side cache.  Remove it again and use the vcredist_x86.exe installer you can download from Microsoft.  Why your machine is building stuff that requires DLLs that are not present on your machine is unguessable from the question, you'd better worry about it a bit.

Comment: Either way, i fixed that problem, another one plagues me

Comment: Great! Add the solution as an answer so it can help others in the future.

Comment: What i only did was copy manually the needed dll to the system32 folder..that took care of the problem with the missing DLL.

As for the R6034 problem, i embedded the manifest file which was generated upon compiling cURL

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to statically link to the crt runtime library.

I don't have VS2010 but in earlier versions, you could go to the project menu, select properties, then select "Configuration Properties" / "C/C++" / "Code Generation" and choose Multithreaded instead of Multithreaded DLL from the "Runtime library" choice for the release configuration.  Or choose Multithreaded Debug instead of Multithreaded Debug DLL for the debug configuration.